# Binary features with 0,0,0, in NN always return 0.5

Tags: neural-network, propagation, sigmoid

Let's assume we have three columns, with binary features (0,1). One row in dataset is 0,0,0 with label 0.

The problem I am facing is:

When assigning weights to this row and activating sigmoid function, I'll always receive 0.5, because an array of zeros products on any weight with 0.

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to multiplication by a weight matrix, you can also add a bias (which is how it is typically done in neural networks), and hence you won't necessarily  get a zero vector. You could also add more hidden layers (but as I said, even adding a bias vector will resolve the issue you mentioned).

Comment: Thanks Miriam. May I just ask. Is it recomended to put bias for every hidden layer or it is enough for one (first one only). Bececause imagine, if I include bias in first hidden layer and countinue  with propagantion to second layer, the result of second layer would act the same as my problem.

Comment: @Makaroniiii Typically every layer contains a bias vector.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a nice day